# Prove that all non negative integers are infinite

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that the set of nonnegative integers ℕ is infinite and that the set of even nonnegative integers is infinite.

To prove that the set ℕ is infinite, there must be a bijection from a proper subset of itself to itself.

Given this information, how would I make a bijection from a subset of itself to itself, this really doesn't make sense to me. Any help clarifying this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, you want to prove that *the set* of non-negative integers *is* infinite. Your title means something else.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the mapping $n \mapsto n/2$. It bijectively maps the even numbers to the naturals.